# How can I keep my SSH sessions from freezing?

Tags: ssh

I have `ServerAliveInterval` and in case of few machines also `ClientAliveInterval` set to 540 in SSH client/server configuration files (I suppose setting it to more than that would not be a good idea). I work with many SSH sessions which currently freeze after a few minutes.

How can I fix it? What I want is to have a session to not freeze at all, so that if I open a session at 8 and don't use it for 4 hours, for example, to still use it again at 12 without having to log-in again.

Comment: How long can you currently stay logged in (assuming this isn't due to network disconnection)? `TCPKeepAlive yes`?

Comment: I am not sure but 10 min. at most. As for `TCPKeepAlive yes` - depends on the machine.

Comment: Just use [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/)?

Comment: Or you could use `autossh`...

Comment: I'd say leaving a connection open for 4 hours is a security concern, and you should be using `screen` instead. But I'm still upvoting your question because I'm experiencing the same issue after only a minute or two.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/37738/

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The changes you've made in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` are correct but will still not have any effect.

To get your configuration working, make these configuration changes on the client:

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 100
```

**ServerAliveInterval**  The client will send a null packet to the server every 100 seconds to keep the connection alive

**NULL packet**  Is sent by the server to the client. The same packet is sent by the client to the server. A TCP NULL packet does not contain any controlling flag like SYN, ACK, FIN etc. because the server does not require a reply from the client. The NULL packet is described here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6592

Then configuring the sshd part on the server.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveCountMax 10000
```

**ClientAliveInterval** The server will wait 60 seconds before sending a null packet to the client to keep the connection alive

**TCPKeepAlive** Is there to ensure that certain firewalls don't drop idle connections.

**ClientAliveCountMax** Server will send alive messages to the client even though it has not received any message back from the client.

Finally restart the `ssh server`

`service ssh restart`  or  `service sshd restart` depending on what system you are on.

Comment: I think a high `ServerAliveCountMax` is also needed in order for this to be as reliable as possible. And if both `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` are set low enough, I don't think there will be any need for `TCPKeepAlive`. Additionally, if there are any middleboxes, they can still lose state even with all of the previously mentioned settings configured exactly correct. It may help to use MPTCP (if both client and server support it).

Comment: It's not clear at the start whether you mean config on the client side or server side (eventually I conclude, client side). Then at **ServerAliveInterval** description, you say "client will send... to the server", but in the next paragraph "**NULL packet** is sent by the server to the client". I find these a bit confusing.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen I've updated my answer and hope this clears things up. The `null packet` is sent by the client to the server  using this directive `ServerAliveInterval` . The server sends the same packet to the client using `ClientAliveInterval`.

Comment: After adding to the server I get: /etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 57: Bad configuration option: clientaliveinterval
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 59: Bad configuration option: clientalivecountmax

Comment: @Anders You get the error because `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` are ssh server options, thus meant for `sshd_config` and not `ssh_config`

Comment: I would love to write a single script that would set these settings for client and server on Debian, Centos, Amazon Linux, and macOS.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky You actually can create your own `.rpm` package that does this. In the `.rpm` package you can include these 2 files and deploy them by installing the package. For debian you could do the same although I'm not so into debian packaging.

Comment: Link to an April fool's joke incorporated into a seriously looking answer :)))

Comment: @ValentinBajrami, I made chnages to `/et/ssh/ssh_config` and after executing `source /etc/ssh/ssh_config`, I got error `No command 'Host' found, did you mean:
 Command 'most' from package 'most' (universe)
 Command 'host' from package 'knot-host' (universe)
 Command 'host' from package 'bind9-host' (main)
Host: command not found
SendEnv: command not found
HashKnownHosts: command not found
GSSAPIAuthentication: command not found
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials: command not found
ServerAliveInterval: command not found
`. What could be wrong. I'm on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @chandresh You cannot source `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` because source is a shell built in and does not work like that. The shell thinks you are trying to execute the lines found in the file. Why are you trying to source the file in question?

Comment: I was sourcing to bring the updates in the file to activate. Does not it need to be sourced like we do for /etc/environment?

Comment: @chandresh you don't have to. After modifying `ssh_config` the new sessions will read that file. The `/etc/environment` file is a different thing which has the format of `VAR="value"`  without spaces thus `VAR = "value"` would be invalid. Sourcing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` that way will i.e read: `Port 22` or `Host *`  which will treat these as commands

Comment: I see. Thanks..

Comment: I had a error with `ClientAliveInterval 60` on the client side.

Answer (score 16):

Personal suggestion: use `screen` on the remote host; it will manage to keep your connection alive for as long as it stays active in a terminal.

Here's what I typically add to `/etc/screenrc` for quick identification of my screen sessions:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][ %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]"
defscrollback 8192
```

---

**EDIT :** Hints.

The `hardstatus` string will show a bottom status line such as this one:
[image: Screen session example with three open tabs]

The scrollback buffer is also extended to 8192 lines instead of the usual 1000-1500 (depending on the distribution).

Comment: Thanks, two questions: 1. Can you explain the options in you `screenrc` file? How do I configure the system the launch screen/tmux right after I login?

Comment: Just to clarify, `screen` does not keep your ssh connection alive. It runs processes in a virtual terminal independent of the user terminal you connect to via `ssh` so the process doesn't rely on your connection. You will still lose your `ssh` connection until it's resolved.

Comment: By "*keep the connection alive*" I essentially mean "*prevents the connection from idling*", which has the same result. If there's no input for 4 hours, SSH *will* go idle and eventually close the connection, all the child processes gone, too.

Comment: As much as I loved `screen`, I advise new users to start with [`tmux`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

Answer (score 7):

If the problem is a hibernated laptop or a less-than-prefect network connection, I'd recommend using [`mosh`](https://mosh.org/) which runs over `ssh` and allows automatic reconnecting.

From the [website](https://mosh.org/):

> Mosh (mobile shell)
>
> Remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes.
>
> Mosh is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.
>
> Mosh is free software, available for GNU/Linux, BSD, macOS, Solaris, Android, Chrome, and iOS.

In combination with `tmux` (or the older `screen`), this allows me to connect via `ssh` to a server from my laptop and stay connected for days even when changing wifi connections and surviving mobile data drop-outs.

Comment: Here is a link to [mosh.org](https://mosh.org/) and to [mosh on Github](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh)

Comment: this feels like the way ssh should be in 2022 - I wonder why this is not more of a thing

Answer (score 2):

With OpenSSH:

You need to enable

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

both in your client ssh_config (e.g. `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or in `~/.ssh/config`) and your destination SSH server running OpenSSH (e.g. /etc/ssh/sshd_config).

So every time your connection idles, OpenSSH sends some dummy packet to your destination host...

Comment: This can also cause the connection to go down `The default is ''yes'' (to send TCP keepalive messages), and the server will notice if the network goes down or the client host crashes.` `...this means that connections will die if the route is down temporarily, and some people find it annoying.` http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config

Comment: Honestly, but `"[…] network goes down […] client host crashes […] route is down […]"` are severe errors no SSH configuration can catch. 

The main issue here are idle SSH sessions, not network failures. Therefore to sum it up:

- enable `TCPKeepAlive yes` in both server and client.
- set `ClientAliveInterval ` on the server
- set `IdleTimeout` on the server
- set `ClientAliveCountMax`

That should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Check your sshd configuration on the host machine `/etc/sshd_config` for the [`IdleTimeout` setting](http://www.employees.org/~satch/ssh/faq/manpages/sshd1_man.html).

```
IdleTimeout time
Sets idle timeout limit to time in seconds (s or nothing afternumber), 
in minutes (m), in hours (h), in days (d), or in weeks (w).If the 
connection have been idle (all channels) for that long time thechild 
process is killed with SIGHUP, and connection is closed down.
```

Answer (score 1):

A little hack I use if it's not possible to use screen, or edit the hosts ssh server settings, or any of the good and proper suggestions above...

Just run top whenever you are going to leave the session alone.

Generally that'll keep it alive indefinitely, although, as others have mentioned, that might not always be wise vis-a-vis security!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the SSH connection used to hang up.

The below solution worked for me. Now the SSH connection always stays live.

**From the server:**

---

1. Edit the file at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```bsh
$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

2. Add or enable this line in the file.

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

3. Save the file and restart the sshd service

```bsh
$ sudo service sshd restart
```

**From the local machine/client:**

---

1. Edit the file at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```bsh
$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

2. Add this line to the file.

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

3. Save the file

**About these Parameters** :

`ServerAliveInterval`: number of seconds that the client will wait before sending a null packet to the server (to keep the connection alive).

`ClientAliveInterval`: number of seconds that the server will wait before sending a null packet to the client (to keep the connection alive).

> Important: Whenever any modification is performed on a Production
> instance, please ensure to create a backup.

Comment: This is in essence the same as accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

- ssh connection remained ESTABLISHED
- terminal freezes and un-freezes repeatedly
- packets are visible in SEND-Q while terminal freezes
- freeze time about 2-4 minutes
- un-frozen for about 30 seconds

Turns out the firmware of my router was outdated!

- fixed issue with firmware update

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in large MTU size. You can change MTU on router if you using NAT, but I change MTU on server:

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 1036
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

My SSH started closing consistently after a minute of being open and I think it was because of a network adapter setting I changed in order to stop my PC from waking up from sleep. My PC had been waking up from sleep for no reason so I found this article on how to stop it and it worked. The article said to go into the Device Manager, find the Ethernet or Wi-Fi adapter in question under Network Adapters, right-click on it, choose Properties, and open the Power Management tab and uncheck the Allow This Device to Wake the Computer.

Alternatively, it said you can keep that box checked, and check Only Allow a Magic Packet to Wake the Computer. I did that and later my SSH would consistently close down after a minute so I believe that was the culprit. So make sure that you don't have that setting on your network adapter changed from the default. Might have to restart your computer for any changes you make to take effect.