# How to keep a vpn ssh socket connection alive?

Tags: ssh, vpn

I'm running the following script to create a connection to a `vpn`.

`sshpass -p <pass> ssh -Nf -C -D <port> <user>@<ip>`

Problem: sometimes the socket shuts down silently (maybe if not in use).

How can I add some kind of "keep alive" statement to the ssh connection?

Comment: Take a look here, seems related to you problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200239/how-can-i-keep-my-ssh-sessions-from-freezing/200256#200256

Comment: [This Q&A is also related](https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open), and uses a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of link provided above, I'm trying now as follows:

`...shh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o TCPKeepAlive=yes`.

I've not had any drops since using it.